# VelocityContext can not get value

Tags: spring, velocity

I send mail using `Spring` and template `engine Velocity`. 
I'm trying to set value to `velocityContext` and then get it in `velocity` template.

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
                velocityContext.put("firstName", "Thomas");
```

And when i debug my code i can see that `velocityContext` gets value "Thomas" but for some reasons when i get this value on view - i get just `${firstName}` like string.

Here is my code.

```
private void sendEmail(final String toEmailAddresses, final String fromEmailAddress,
                           final String subject, final String attachmentPath,
                           final String attachmentName) {
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                message.setTo(toEmailAddresses);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
                velocityContext.put("firstName", "Thomas");
                String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
                        velocityEngine, "templates/registration.vm", "UTF-8", null);
                message.setText(body, true);
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(attachmentPath)) {
                    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(attachmentPath);
                    message.addAttachment(attachmentName, file);
                }
            }
        };
        this.mailSender.send(preparator);
    }
```

and template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
     <body>
         Hi, ${firstName}<br/> 
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making use of `VelocityContext` that you have created and initialized. If you are using `eclipse IDE`, this would have displayed as a warning. `VelocityEngineUtils` does not accept `VelocityContext` as a parameter in any of its methods.

There are two approaches:

- Either, make use of `VelocityEngine` and then make a call to `VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate` which takes `VelocityContext` as an input parameter.
- Use `VelocityEngineUtils` and pass a `Map` *model* that maps the placeholders in the template with actual values. I would recommend this as your use case looks quite straight-forward.

Instead of

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
velocityContext.put("firstName", "Thomas");
String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "templates/registration.vm", "UTF-8", null);
```

Use

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("firstName", "Thomas");
String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "templates/registration.vm", "UTF-8", model);
```